# web2py internal error in query

Tags: python, web2py, web2py-modules

I'm testing mysql database in web2py but I have little problem on display a basic results in select query.

Models
blog_page.py

```
from gluon import DAL
from gluon import Field

db = DAL('mysql://root:@localhost/pythonblogdb')

db.define_table(
'blog_page',
Field('title', type='password'),
Field('content', type='string', writable=True, readable=True, default=''),
Field('publish_date', type='datetime', writable=True, readable=True, default=''),
)
db.commit()
```

Controller
def insert_blog():

```
rows = db(db.blog_page).select()
return dict(rows=rows)
```

Views
inser_blog.html

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{=rows}}
```

I having an Internal error on this one why?

Comment: No worries I resolve by retyping the code.

Comment: In a model file, no need to import `DAL` or `Field` or to call `db.commit()` after the table definition.

Comment: oh thank you for the tips Anthony. =)